# how c# compiler works?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction

how c# compiler works??

how it parses our whole solutions and .cs files... i want to know where it start and how everything works... i want to know from the asp.net perspective...

thx

Comment: May be Jon Skeet knows..

Comment: This question is not really very focused so I doubt you'll get a good answer here that doesn't just point you to specialised literature.

Comment: This question is much too vague. You need to go learn how programming languages and compilers work before anyone could explain to you how the C# compiler, in particular, works.

Comment: That's really a huge question. Compilers are incredibly complex especially for a beginner.

Comment: The authoritative SO question of *writing* compilers and interpreters is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler . That might be too deep for you, but if you can program at all you can read he Crenshaw tutorial (linked in that question) and come out knowing something useful about compilers.

Answer (score 6):

If you're really interested in how a C# compiler works, you may want to [read the source code from Mono's compiler, mcs](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs).

Comment: This is actually quite interesting.

Comment: This link no longer works, it need to be updated.

Answer (score 4):

Eric Lippert gave a great synopsis of the C# compiler in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917935/how-does-c-compilation-get-around-needing-header-files/1918663#1918663).

Answer (score 1):

A really brief explanation could be:

- In Asp.net, you write an page.aspx file that get compiled into a .Net assembly, this assembly is then used by the Asp.Net runtime that execute http request.
- This .Net assembly can be written in any .Net language like c# or VB.Net. But in the end, the code is compiled by the .Net [CLR](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) compiler into a [Common Intermediary Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)(CIL). This CIL is used by the CLR runtime which get loaded when you start a .Net process. The [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) then use this CIL and transform it into pure assembly that will be understandable by the computer.